# Squid deployment not working

Tags: subsquid, docker

I'm slowly making my way to deploying a squid. Earlier I had some issues with a deploy error due to lack of an up-to-date repo.
I'm currently facing a new challenge. When releasing the squid to the site, the original `deploy_error` has gone away, but it is still not finalizing the sync.

Running the `npx sqd squid tail`  command to see what happens just sends an html Server Error:  502

The Subsquid App shows "Deploying" in a constant hang for >30 minutes.

[image: hang1]

[image: deploy hang II]

It appears that when deploying, the constant hang could be due to my db not initializing.  When I go to the Query node playground, I get the following errors when trying to query.

[image]

Running my squid locally, and executing cmd: `docker build . -t squid-template:latest --no-cache` I'm getting: `Successfully tagged squid-template:latest build before deploying.` message.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I pulled and tried running the files on a Windows OS, and saw that I kept getting the following error

```
TypeORM: QueryFailedError: relation 'remarks' does not exist
```

Going into the db/init.js file I changed the `synchronize`: option to `true`

```
const ormconfig = {
  type: 'postgres',
  // entities: [require.resolve('../lib/model')],
  entities: [],
  migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/*.js'],
  synchronize: true,
  migrationsRun: false,
  dropSchema: false,
   //....
}
```

[image]

Now works!